# How to test a Vue 3 watcher inside setup function based on an external composable computed property

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3

I am facing a problem while trying to test a component that is using external logic in a composable. I am using Vue 2.7 and Typescript 4.5. The component basically looks like this:

```js
export default Vue.extend({
  setup() {
    const {
      isLoading: isLoadingProducts
    } = usePromotionProducts();

    watch(isLoadingProducts, newIsLoadingProducts => {
      doSomething();
    });

    return {
      isLoading
    };
  }
```

The composable looks like this:

```js
export function usePromotionProducts() {
  const isLoading = computed(() => /* stuff here /*)
  return {
    isLoading
  };
```

Using Jest, I'd like to be able to spy on the return of `usePromotionProducts()`. For typing issue, I need to provide a computed property to the mocked response:

```js
jest.spyOn(composables, 'usePromotionProducts').mockReturnValue({
  isLoading: computed(() => false)
});
```

By doing so, I can't find how should I act on the `isLoading` computed so that it triggers the `watch` callback and therefore the `doSomething()` function. I think it might be better to provide a `ref` to the mocked response instead of a `computed`, but it doesn't fit the function's return type definition.
Thanks in advance for any advice!